# SQLite DB migration to copy, parse and paste data to another column

Tags: sql, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have a column called `start_time` which is of String type inside `my_table`. I would like to create an additional column named `start_time_int` (additional, because some parts of the project require the String type whereas some would do better with the int type) where I copy all the values from `start_time`, parse them to long and paste them to `start_time_int`. Is this sort of migration possible with just SQL commands?

Comment: Adding sample data and desired result would be helpful. (not image)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is this sort of migration possible with just SQL commands?

Yes, at least the end result can be achieved.

However, **the format of start_time matters**.

Furthermore, there is probably no need for a migration as it is very likely, again the format of start_time matters, to dynamically convert the result and to not store the same information twice.

Assuming that start_time is in the format YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm e.g. 2021-10-01 10:25 then as the format is an SQLite recognised format you can get the long version using `strftime('%s',start_time) AS start_time_int` when querying the  table and there will be a start_time_int column that is an INTEGER (long).

Here's a Demo App that shows both techniques based upon a start_time in the format as above.

The database has two tables **table1** and **table2** which initially have the same schema an **_id** column and a **start_time** column.

When the database version is increased to 2 from 1 then an additional column **start_time_int** is added in the `onUpgrade` method via an **`ALTER TABLE table1 ADD COLUMN start_time_int INTEGER`**, this being followed by an **`UPDATE table1 SET start_time_int = strftime('%s',start_time) WHERE start_time_int IS NULL;`** this setting the **start_time_int** value (which as there is no DEFAULT specified in the start_time_int column definition is set to null).

- Note that to cater for new installs, that the `onCreate` version has also been changed. As this has demo been designed for testing the switch between versions the `onCreate` method has logic to apply the respective table creation.

However, table2 remains unchanged. This table is used to demonstrates that there is no need to change the table as the Long value can easily be extracted.

The Database Helper (the class that extends SQLiteOpenHelper) **DBHelper** :-

```
class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public  static final String DBNAME = "thedatabase.db";
    public static final int DBVERSION = 1; /*<<<<<<<< */
    public static final String TABLE1_NAME = "table1";
    public static final String TABLE2_NAME = "table2";
    public static final String ID_COLUMN = BaseColumns._ID;
    public static final String START_TIME_COLUMN = "start_time";
    public static final String START_TIME_INT_COLUMN = "start_time_int";

    SQLiteDatabase db;

    private static volatile DBHelper instance;

    private DBHelper(Context context) {
        super(context,DBNAME,null,DBVERSION);
        db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    }

    public static DBHelper getInstance(Context context) {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new DBHelper(context);
        }
        return instance;
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        if (DBVERSION == 1) {
            db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE1_NAME + " (" +
                    ID_COLUMN + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY" +
                    ", " + START_TIME_COLUMN + " TEXT" +
                    ")");
        } else {
            db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE1_NAME + " (" +
                    ID_COLUMN + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY" +
                    ", " + START_TIME_COLUMN + " TEXT " +
                    ", " + START_TIME_INT_COLUMN + " INTEGER " +
                    ")");
        }
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE2_NAME + " (" +
                ID_COLUMN + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY" +
                ", " + START_TIME_COLUMN + " TEXT" +
                ")");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        if (oldVersion < 2) {
            Log.d("ONUPGRADE", "On Upgrade called. Oldversion is " + oldVersion + " New version is " + newVersion);
            db.execSQL("ALTER TABLE " + TABLE1_NAME + " ADD COLUMN " + START_TIME_INT_COLUMN + " INTEGER;");
            db.execSQL("UPDATE " + TABLE1_NAME + " SET " + START_TIME_INT_COLUMN + " = strftime('%s'," + START_TIME_COLUMN + ") WHERE " + START_TIME_INT_COLUMN + " IS NULL;");
        }
    }

    public long insert(String tableName, String start_time) {
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(START_TIME_COLUMN,start_time);
        return db.insert(tableName,null,cv);
    }

    @SuppressLint("Range")
    public void logTable2() {
        Cursor csr = db.query(TABLE2_NAME,
                new String[]{
                        ID_COLUMN,
                        START_TIME_COLUMN,
                        "strftime('%s'," + START_TIME_COLUMN + ") AS " + START_TIME_INT_COLUMN
                },
                null,null,null,null,null
        );
        while(csr.moveToNext()) {
            Log.d(
                    "TABLE2INFO",
                    "StartTime = " + csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex(START_TIME_COLUMN)) +
                            " AS INTEGER(long) " + csr.getLong(csr.getColumnIndex(START_TIME_INT_COLUMN))
            );
        }
    }

    @SuppressLint("Range")
    public void logTable1V1() {
        Cursor csr = db.query(TABLE2_NAME,
                null, /* (all columns) */
                null,null,null,null,null
        );
        while(csr.moveToNext()) {
            Log.d(
                    "TABLE1V1INFO",
                    "StartTime = " + csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex(START_TIME_COLUMN))
            );
        }
    }

    @SuppressLint("Range")
    public void logTable1V2() {
        Cursor csr = db.query(TABLE1_NAME,
                null, /* (all columns) */
                null,null,null,null,null
        );
        DatabaseUtils.dumpCursor(csr);
        while(csr.moveToNext()) {
            Log.d(
                    "TABLE1V2INFO",
                    "StartTime = " + csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex(START_TIME_COLUMN)) +
                            " AS INTEGER(Long)" + csr.getLong(csr.getColumnIndex(START_TIME_INT_COLUMN))
            );
        }
    }
}
```

- Note the 3 logTable?? methods one for V1 of table1, one for V2 of table1 and one for table2 which is unchanged.

Here's the code in an Activity i.e. **MainActivity** that opens the database, inserts some rows into table1 and table2 when the version is 1, the rows being the same for each table. If the version is 1 the `logTableV1` method is used to write the data to the log. If the version is 2 then the `logTableV2` is used to write the table to the log with the new **start_time_int** value.

In both cases the `logTable2` method writes the start_time AND the start_time_int which has been dynamically generated in the SQL.

**Results**

Run 1 - new Install with Version 1 :-

```
2021-10-23 08:10:33.974 D/TABLE1V1INFO: StartTime = 2021-10-01 10:25
2021-10-23 08:10:33.974 D/TABLE1V1INFO: StartTime = 2021-10-02 11:15
2021-10-23 08:10:33.975 D/TABLE2INFO: StartTime = 2021-10-01 10:25 AS INTEGER(long) 1633083900
2021-10-23 08:10:33.975 D/TABLE2INFO: StartTime = 2021-10-02 11:15 AS INTEGER(long) 1633173300
```

Run 2 - Version changed to 2 :-

```
2021-10-23 08:15:23.944 D/TABLE1V2INFO: StartTime = 2021-10-01 10:25 AS INTEGER(Long)1633083900
2021-10-23 08:15:23.944 D/TABLE1V2INFO: StartTime = 2021-10-02 11:15 AS INTEGER(Long)1633173300
2021-10-23 08:15:23.945 D/TABLE2INFO: StartTime = 2021-10-01 10:25 AS INTEGER(long) 1633083900
2021-10-23 08:15:23.945 D/TABLE2INFO: StartTime = 2021-10-02 11:15 AS INTEGER(long) 1633173300
```

As previously stated the format of the **start_time** matters, if it is not YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm, then changes to the above would likely be required. However, the principle of either extracting the reformatted data dynamically or altering the table followed by an update apply.

You may wish to consider reading [SQLite - Date and Time Functions](https://sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html)